# Typescript intersection and useStoreActions hook gives me "Type has no call signatures.ts(2349)" error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to do [generalizing](https://easy-peasy.now.sh/docs/recipes/generalising-models.html) and code splitting with store addModel/removeModel functions at model level, with typescript and [easy-peasy](https://easy-peasy.now.sh/).

[There is a sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/easy-peasy-typescript-no-call-signature-error-86xqz) for the problem illustration.

I get the

> This expression is not callable.Type 'Computed<CommonModuleModel, string[], StoreModel>' has no call signatures.ts(2349)

error message.

I see this is a common issue with ts, I checked a number of posts about it, but cannot figure out, how to avoid this error in my case.

There is a newmodule.tsx component, which is lazily loaded, and it adds it's own slice to the model level, but cannot call the nextTodos function from the generalized commonModuleModel model.

How can I get this functionality?